# Old love letters - but who wrote them?

Tags: wordplay, story, literature

I recently discovered some old love letters, I estimate that some of them date back as much as 40 years. Here are some snippets from a few of them$\ldots$

> We share so many *little* memories that never fade, *persisting over long periods of time without changing*. My love for you is how *they all combine* into a beautiful whole that is so much more than any of them individually. I treasure these, holding on to them as if trying to *prevent anyone else from taking them away*.

---

> When I'm not with you I sometimes think about undressing you, *dismantling your clothing one thread at a time* so that it lasts much longer before I have to return to my day. Your *natural beauty* is so *bright and colourful* I feel overwhelmed. It's as if you *shower* me with *arrows* and play my heart-*strings* like a *violin*, *tying* me up in *knots*.

---

> It's like I have a *hunger* for you, to know more about you, to fathom how you can possibly be so *incredible*. The more I know you, the more I am amazed by the intricacies of your beauty and character. This *admiration* only *whets* my *desire* further.

---

Who wrote these?

**Update:** Over the weekend, I went through some more papers from the same box. Most were boring but there also was another love letter. I've included a snippet from it below. Further, I noticed that some of the words were underlined in a different pen which had almost faded away, and I've added emphasis to those words in the snippets above and below.

> Without you, I *cannot see*. It's as if I've *never seen*. I continue about my business, wishing you were with me, but really I'm just *marking time*. *Creating* new ways to *count the seconds* until I will see you once again.

---

I found another one$\ldots$

> Before we met, my life felt like I was trudging up an infinite *mountain*. Step after step; *hand-hold after foot-hold*; toward a summit I wasn't sure was even there. But on the day I met you, I knew I had indeed reached the summit. I thought about it when I got home and realised how *unlikely* our meeting was, how if any one of a million little things was different then it never would have happened, and that's how I knew.

Comment: Are we looking for one or three authors?

Comment: third paragraph surely talks about pizza :D

Comment: @Alconja all of the letters are written in the same hand.

Comment: Getting a physics vibe with the hint. Particles, fusion, stars, string theory, atomic clocks...

Comment: @Alconja There's certainly an academic science vibe, yes, but the style of these letters seems much more more down to earth.

Comment: I have to come out of character to say this... Those love letter snippets I've written sound so sappy and pathetic - please someone solve this so I don't have to write any more. Each one represents a different book by this author and alludes to the title and (loosely) to the general content/message of the book.

Comment: Ooops, was writing a nonsense partial answer while you were updating. The second love letter happened to match a certain word too well to resist. More power to the passion in your pen, [Abelard/Heloise](http://www.abelardandheloise.com/Story.html)!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> Richard Dawkins (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Dawkins)

---

### Explanation

We share so many *little* memories that never fade, *persisting over long periods of time without changing*. My love for you is how *they all combine* into a beautiful whole that is so much more than any of them individually. I treasure these, holding on to them as if trying to *prevent anyone else from taking them away*.

> *little*, *they all combine*, *prevent anyone else from taking them away* allude to:
>  "The Selfish Gene", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Selfish_Gene

---

When I'm not with you I sometimes think about undressing you, *dismantling your clothing one thread at a time* so that it lasts much longer before I have to return to my day. Your *natural beauty* is so *bright and colourful* I feel overwhelmed. It's as if you *shower* me with *arrows* and play my heart-*strings* like a *violin*, *tying* me up in *knots*.

> *dismantling your clothing one thread at a time*, *natural beauty*, *bright and colourful* allude to:
>  "Unweaving the Rainbow", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unweaving_the_Rainbow

---

It's like I have a *hunger* for you, to know more about you, to fathom how you can possibly be so *incredible*. The more I know you, the more I am amazed by the intricacies of your beauty and character. This *admiration* only *whets* my *desire* further.

> *hunger*, *incredible*, *admiration*, *desire* allude to:
>  "An Appetite for Wonder", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Appetite_for_Wonder

---

Without you, I *cannot see*. It's as if I've *never seen*. I continue about my business, wishing you were with me, but really I'm just *marking time*. *Creating* new ways to *count the seconds* until I will see you once again.

> *cannot see*, *never seen*, *marking time*, *Creating* allude to:
>  "The Blind Watchmaker", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blind_Watchmaker

---

Before we met, my life felt like I was trudging up an infinite *mountain*. Step after step; *hand-hold after foot-hold*; toward a summit I wasn't sure was even there. But on the day I met you, I knew I had indeed reached the summit. I thought about it when I got home and realised how *unlikely* our meeting was, how if any one of a million little things was different then it never would have happened, and that's how I knew.

> *mountain*, *hand-hold after foot-hold*, *unlikely*  allude to:
>  "Climbing Mount Improbable", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climbing_Mount_Improbable

Answer (score 2):

Here is just some of the damage possible
when personal correspondence falls into the wrong hands.

In the spirit of partial answers,

> each love letter might be a different part of the answer,
>  perhaps even an actual alphabetical letter.

If so, the second love letter might refer to

> “bow” or the writer's beau, Bo.

- When I'm not with you I sometimes think about undressing you,
  *dismantling your clothing one thread at a time*
  so that it lasts much longer before I have to return to my day.

  > hair bow? ribbon bows instead of buttons for clothing?
  >    [not off to a great start here]
- Your *natural beauty* is so *bright and colourful* I feel overwhelmed.
  It's as if you *shower* me

  > rainbow
- with *arrows* and play my heart-*strings*

  > archery bow, bowstring
- like a *violin*

  > violin bow
- *tying* me up

  > bow tie
- in *knots*.

  > bowknot

The fourth love letter might refer to

> C or “sea.”

- Without you, I *cannot see*. It's as if I've *never seen*.

  > see why it might be C?
- I continue about my business, wishing you were with me,
  but really I'm just *marking time*.

  > in music, the marking for *common time* is 
  >  <sub><sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub></sub>
- *Creating* new ways to *count the seconds*

  > <sup><sup>14</sup></sup>C (carbon-14) dating
- until I will see you once again.

  > double CC ?

Comment: This is a great way to approach it, but unfortunately I'm not clever enough to devise such a devious puzzle! Each snippet is a book - see comment on question.